# how to hide systemtray in landscape

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, show-hide, system-tray, orientation-changes

How to change in windows phone the systemtray in portrait to show up and on landscape to hide?!

i have something like this now but it dont work:

```
void Pregled_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
        {
            SystemTray.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

on the xaml page the shell:systemtray.isvisible="true" and it dont work. if i remove the visiblity from systemtray in xaml it is not shown at all.

i fixed it, it was an little bug in my code, i had to use PhoneApplicationPage_BeginLayoutChanged instead of Pregled_OrientationChanged i thought i can set the event handler name like i want... my mistake.

Comment: In the `VisualStateManager` there should be a `VisualStateGroup` named `OrientationStates` where you can apply your Visibility changes based on whether its Landscape or Portrait State.

Comment: in xaml i have nothing similar to a visual state group, i dont know what you mean. i think this code above should work but it doesnt. is there a way to improve it so it work?!

Comment: I just tried your code and it work for me... Are you sure you registered Pregled_OrientationChanged?

Comment: What do you mean by registered, i have no errors in visual studio if i compile it this way but if i rotate my device either on the device or emulator the systemtray stays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code made it to work...

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_BeginLayoutChanged (object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
    {
        SystemTray.IsVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```